# Coinbase API send money transaction hash

Tags: php, cryptography, coinbase-api

I am trying to send payment using coinbase.com wallet API. I found a code on GitHub, using it I successfully sent payment to LTC address. Here's the code:

```
<?php
        include 'vendor/autoload.php';
        $apiKey = 'MY_API_HERE';
        $apiSecret = 'MY_SECRET_HERE';

        use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;

        $configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);
        $client = Client::create($configuration);

        use Coinbase\Wallet\Enum\CurrencyCode;
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Transaction;
        use Coinbase\Wallet\Value\Money;

        $accountId = "MY_LTC_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE";

        $account = $client->getAccount($accountId);

        $transaction = Transaction::send([
            'toBitcoinAddress' => 'PAYMENT_ADDRESS',
            'amount' => new Money(AMOUNT_OF_LTC_HERE, CurrencyCode::LTC)
        ]); 


   try { 
      $client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction); 
   }
   catch(Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
   }
?>
```

My included files are here https://darkchannel.info/coinbase/vendor.zip

But I don't know how to get the transaction hash (coin transaction id).

Answer (score 1):

You still have initial transaction as `$transaction`, so after creating the transaction in the network, you can access the hash using this code `$transaction->getNetwork()-> getHash()`.

Comment: i tried by adding your suggestion by adding `$hash = $transaction->getNetwork()-> getHash(); print_r($hash);` both after and before of  `try { 
      $client->createAccountTransaction($account, $transaction);` , but it still not printing something!

Comment: You should add it after the try section. What does it return?

Comment: When i added `$data = $transaction->getNetwork()-> getHash(); print_r($data)` after try catch section it echo nothing, the page was full blank. But when i did added `$data = $transaction->getNetwork(); print_r($data)` it echo this https://darkchannel.info/coinbase/result.png but still hash missing :(

Comment: Hello Sir! Please Reply